# How to manually manage offsets/commits to avoid receiving duplicate message and losing data?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have recently started working with Kafka and I am trying to setup Kafka consumer that will listen to kafka in production. I was reading about `Commits` and `Offsets` and it looks like Kafka provides a way of tracking which records were read by a consumer of the group.

Clearly managing offsets has large impact on the client application. Automatic commits are convenient, but they don’t give developers enough control to avoid duplicate messages so I am planning to manually manage the offsets myself both to **eliminate the possibility of missing messages and to reduce the number of messages duplicated during rebalancing.**

I saw this [github code](https://github.com/ajmalbabu/kafka-clients/blob/master/src/main/java/poc/ExactlyOnceDynamicConsumer.java) where offsets is being managed manually by writing it on a disk. In my case, I am using the same idea but managing the offsets in a database table as in my case, I will have multiple consumers running on a different machine consuming data from the same topic so I am planning to store offsets data given a topic and partition into the database so that all the machine knows about what was the last offset for that topic/partition if any rebalance occurs.

Below is my consumer code where I `poll` data from kafka:

```
  private static final OffsetManager offsetManager = new OffsetManager("storage2");
  private KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer;

  @Override
  protected void run(String consumerName, Properties consumerProps) {
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
    consumer.subscribe(getTopicsBasedOnConsumerName(), new KafkaRebalanceListener(consumer));

    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(Config.URLS, TEST_URL);
    GenericRecordDomainDataDecoder decoder = new GenericRecordDomainDataDecoder(config);

    while (true) {
      ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
      for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
        GenericRecord payload = decoder.decode(record.value());
        // extract data from payload
        // save all these data and then manually commit offsets as below

        offsetManager.saveOffsetInExternalStore(record.topic(), record.partition(),
            record.offset());           
      }
    }
  }
```

and Below is my `KafkaRebalanceListener` class:

```
public class KafkaRebalanceListener implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
  private final OffsetManager offsetManager = new OffsetManager("storage2");
  private final Consumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer;

  public KafkaRebalanceListener(KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer) {
    this.consumer = consumer;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
      offsetManager.saveOffsetInExternalStore(partition.topic(), partition.partition(),
          consumer.position(partition));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
      consumer.seek(partition,
          offsetManager.readOffsetFromExternalStore(partition.topic(), partition.partition()));
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my `saveOffsetInExternalStore` and `readOffsetFromExternalStore` method in the `OffsetManager` class:

```
public void saveOffsetInExternalStore(String topic, int partition, long offset) {
    String sql = "insert into manage_offset (topic, partition, offset) values (?, ?, ?)";
    // insert/update offset given a topic and partition
    // my primary key in the table is "topic + partition"
}

// returning offset + 1
public long readOffsetFromExternalStore(String topic, int partition) {
    String sql = "select * from manage_offset where topic=? and partition=?";
    try {
        // return offset from the table given a topic and partition if we finds it
        long offset = row.getLong("offset");
        return offset + 1;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // log error
    }
    // else return 0
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

1. What is the real benefit we are getting with this "exactly-once scenario" as compared to enabling automated commit? Under what scenarios and case, this will help. I want to eliminate the possibility of missing messages and to reduce the number of messages duplicated during rebalancing and that's why I am thinking of considering this approach. While it may often seem feasible, but I guess it should never be relied upon because there are always caveats. Even with this pattern the consumer can't guarantee it won't reprocess a message after a failure. What if the consumer consumes a message and then fails before the offset is flushed to disk or written into database? If you write to disk/database before you process the message, what if you write the offset and then fail before actually processing the message? This same problem would exist even if you were to commit offsets to ZooKeeper after every message.
2. And other question I have is, right now I am managing offsets in a database table instead of writing into a disk of each machine as the above github code does that. Bcoz in my case I will have multiple consumers running on different machine so managing offsets onto a disk will be a problem I guess. let's say if we have 3 consumers (C1, C2 and C3, each running on a different machine) consuming a topic with three partitions (P1, P2, P3) so each consumer will be assigned one partition and they will consume data from them. For example: C1 is working on P1, C2 is working on P2 and C3 is working on P3 all on different machine. And as per the github code, it will keep writing offsets to that machine disk but let's say if one machine (C1 went down) went down and now we have two machines so let's say C2 after rebalance will also work on P1 along with P2 but C2 consumer/machine doesn't know anything about the last offset for P1 partition so it will get 0? So to solve this case should I use centralized database where all the machines writes/update offsets given a topic and partition and read offset given a topic and partition into the database table? Do you guys think this is feasible approach? Bcoz in my case, I will have multiple consumers running on a different machine consuming data from the same topic and I am planning to store offsets data given a topic and partition into the database so that all the machine knows about what was the last offset for that topic/partition if any rebalance occurs?

   CREATE TABLE manage_offset (
     topic text,
     partition int,
     offset bigint,
     PRIMARY KEY (topic, partition)
   );

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647656/effective-strategy-to-avoid-duplicate-messages-in-apache-kafka-consumer for the answer.

Comment: Getting exactly-once processing is currently only possible with Kafka if you have idempotent operation -- ie, the final state of you application is the same even if you process some message multiple times. No matter if you use an external system, or do auto-commit, or manual-commits. There is always the possibility that you can lose some information resulting in duplicate processing of some messages. You can only build you application in an duplicate-agnostic way.

Comment: Btw: there is no reason why not just commit offsets to Kafka itself -- if you use an DB to store offsets, you do not gain anything with regard to duplicate handling. It's not better or worse.