# How to avoid duplication in Kafka when consumer got disconnected ..I am able to see previous messages every time

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to implement a simple Producer-->Kafka-->Consumer application in Kafka Shell . I am able to produce as well as consume the messages successfully, but the problem occurs when I restart the consumer,every time when I restart consumer old messages get picked up.Is there any way to avoid so that failed messages while I restarting consumer get only picked up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effective strategy to avoid duplicate messages in apache kafka consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647656/effective-strategy-to-avoid-duplicate-messages-in-apache-kafka-consumer)

Comment: Check the offset commit in your consumer . As long as your consumer commits the offset  for each message and belongs to same group-id while reconnecting, you will receive duplicate messages

Answer (score 0):

From the shell... Meaning `kafka-console-consumer`? If so:

1. Don't constantly use `--from-beginning`
2. Add `--group` argument to keep track of what has been consumed

Its worth mentioning that the default behavior is at-least once delivery, so duplicates should be expected and you'll need to write a different consumer to accommodate idempotent / transactional producers