# How to restrict a Kafka Topic from being consumed more than once?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka topic named SEND_NOTIFICATION that is used to send the notifications that notification service uses. But the issue is, after the topic has been consumed by listener and I use debug mode while inside any function in this module, the topic is then consumed again and notifications are sent again and again.

Is there any solution to restrict it from being consumed again?

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836412/681929)

Comment: This probably means that your consumer (group) isn't committing offsets on its partitions, so will receive them again if it disconnects. It can also happen if you use a random consumer group each time you connect and you have auto.offset.reset set to 'earliest'

Comment: @nobalG That is about duplicates in the topic, not processing offsets more than once in a consumer when it mishandles commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is, no, not easily.

Kafka persists data after consumption. It is not the same as other solutions like AWS SNS or RabbitMQ that remove data once consumed.

---

If you set `group.id` to some consistent value, **and** set `enable.auto.commit=false` config, **and** call `commitSync()` in your consumer **after** reading the data, you will resume data from **next available** offset on the next run.

But, this means, while debugging, you may be skipping offsets, and not processing the data you expect.

However, as soon as `group.id` is set to something else, or you run `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets`, you will read the data again, since it still exists in the broker.

Answer (score 0):

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
```

I think this property in the consumer configs will help.